# embracing operator inside mutate function

Tags: r, operators, tidyverse, dplyr

I'm trying to write a function I'm frequently in my dissertation but having a hard time getting it to run.

The code works but then fails once I run the function, I think, because of how R reads in the designated variable via the embracing function options. Here is the successful code for one variable, prburden and a [link to sample data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3d3ustpye83pvaf/rburden_data2.rds?dl=0):

```
 rburden_data2 %>%
  
  # select only percent rent burden vars
  select(tractid, year, CBSA_name, contains("prburden")) %>%
  
  # group by tractid and count # of tracts by group 
  group_by(tractid) %>% 
  
  # create rent burden change indicator - continuous
  mutate(cont_chg_prburden = prburden[year == "2019"] - prburden[year == "2000"] ) %>%
  
  # create rent burden change indicator - categorical
  mutate(cat_chg_prburden = case_when(cont_chg_prburden   < 0 ~ "negative",
                                      cont_chg_prburden  == 0 ~ "zero",
                                      cont_chg_prburden   > 0  ~ "positive" ,
                                      TRUE ~ "NA")) %>%
  
  
  # create rent burden change indicator - binary
  mutate(bi_chg_prburden = case_when(cat_chg_prburden == "negative" ~ "loss",
                                     cat_chg_prburden == "positive" ~ "gain",
                                     TRUE ~ "NA")) %>%
  glimpse()
```

in this command I :

- take my dataset (rburden_data2)
- subset only with vital variables
- group by census tract (tractid)
- create a continuous indicator of the difference between first and last year rent burden
- create a categorical indicator of negative, zero, and positive change
- create a binary indicator of gain or loss over study period

Here's the function I'm trying to run where I specify the same variable, prburden:

```
# function  ++++++++++++++++++++
change_indicators <- function(data, var){
  
  data %>%
    
    # select only percent rent burden vars
    select(tractid, year, contains("prburden")) %>%
    
    # group by tractid and count # of tracts by group 
    group_by(tractid) %>% 
    
    # create rent burden change indicator - continuous
    mutate("cont_chg_{{ var }} ":= "{{var}}"[year == 2019] - "{{var}}"[year == 2000]) %>%
    
    # create rent burden change indicator - categorical
    mutate("cat_chg_{{ var }}" := case_when("cont_chg_{{ var }}"    < 0 ~ "negative",
                                             "cont_chg_{{ var }}"   == 0 ~ "zero",
                                             "cont_chg_{{ var }}"    > 0  ~ "positive" ,
                                             TRUE ~ "NA")) %>%
    
    
    # create rent burden change indicator - binary
    mutate("bi_chg_{{ var }}" := case_when("cat_chg_{{ var }}" == "negative" ~ "loss",
                                           "cat_chg_{{ var }}" == "positive" ~ "gain",
                                           TRUE ~ "NA")) %>%
    
    
    
    glimpse() 
  
}

# test ++++++++++++++++++++
test <-  change_indicators(data = rburden_data2, 
                           var = prburden)  

# error ++++++++++++++++++++
Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `cont_chg_prburden `.
ℹ `cont_chg_prburden  = "{{var}}"[year == 2019] - "{{var}}"[year == 2000]`.
x non-numeric argument to binary operator
ℹ The error occurred in group 1: tractid = "01001020100".
```

The problem, I'm running into is when I pass the variable "prburden" through all the name changes and then call it to calculate year differences. I'm a pretty confused on how to use the {{}} operators bc I would think I wouldn't need the "" after the first := but it throws an error.

Any help converting my first code chunk to executable function would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, @RonakShah. I've included an example data set and reformatted the question a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this function -

```
library(dplyr)

change_indicators <- function(data, var){
  val <- deparse(substitute(var))
  col1 <- paste0('cont_chg_', val)
  col2 <- paste0('cat_chg_', val)
  col3 <- paste0('bi_chg_', val)
  
  data %>%
    # select only percent rent burden vars
    select(tractid, year, contains("prburden")) %>%
    # group by tractid and count # of tracts by group 
    group_by(tractid) %>% 
    # create rent burden change indicator - continuous
    mutate(!! col1 := {{var}}[year == 2019] - {{var}}[year == 2000],
           !! col2  := case_when(.data[[col1]]    < 0 ~ "negative",
                                .data[[col1]]   == 0 ~ "zero",
                                .data[[col1]]    > 0  ~ "positive" ,
                                TRUE ~ NA_character_), 
           !!col3 := case_when(.data[[col2]] == "negative" ~ "loss",
                                .data[[col2]] == "positive" ~ "gain",
                                TRUE ~ NA_character_)) %>%
    glimpse() 
  
}
```

- Use `{{var}}` when using the column names directly.
- I am not sure if `"cont_chg_{{ var }}"` works, I prefer to use `.data` pronoun there.
- To assign column names use `!!name :=` to create new columns.
- Replaced "NA" with `NA_character_`
- Combined everything into one `mutate` call.

```
data %>%
  ungroup %>%
  change_indicators(prburden)

#Rows: 219,246
#Columns: 10
#Groups: tractid [73,082]
#$ tractid           <chr> "01001020100", "01001020100", "01001020100"…
#$ year              <chr> "2000", "2013", "2019", "2000", "2013", "20…
#$ prburden_no       <dbl> 60.73620, 67.88991, 44.64286, 46.07843, 42.…
#$ prburden          <dbl> 14.110429, 13.761468, 35.119048, 16.666667,…
#$ prburden_sev      <dbl> 17.177914, 18.348624, 18.452381, 26.470588,…
#$ prburden_not      <dbl> 7.975460, 0.000000, 1.785714, 10.784314, 10…
#$ prburden_all      <dbl> 31.28834, 32.11009, 53.57143, 43.13725, 46.…
#$ cont_chg_prburden <dbl> 21.008618, 21.008618, 21.008618, 7.457847, …
#$ cat_chg_prburden  <chr> "positive", "positive", "positive", "positi…
#$ bi_chg_prburden   <chr> "gain", "gain", "gain", "gain", "gain", "ga…
```

Comment: Great, thanks Ronak, this totally worked. I'm frustrated too bc I haven't see ` "cont_chg_{{ var }}"` work in the wild very often.

Comment: The follow up question is how to be able to get the function to run for multiple variables. I've tried : `vars <-  c("prburden", "prburden_sev", "prburden_all")
mytest <- map_df(vars, change_indicators(data = rburden_data,
            var = vars))` but it keeps throwing an error: ` x non-numeric argument to binary operator`. I can't figure out how to get the function to read the var names in the vector as var names and not characters. I tried the `deparse(substitute(var))` to no avail.

Comment: For multiple variables I think you should use them as character variables. There is no easy way to treat them as variables without quotes.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance here, but how do I do that? I thought the problem was that it's reading them as characters and needs them as not.

Comment: Actually, that would require to change the answer completely. Moreover, instead of calling the function as `change_indicators(prburden)` you need to pass the variable as string `change_indicators("prburden")` . Can you ask that as a new question so that we can keep these two approaches separate?

Answer (score 2):

I found that the easiest approach is to define your new variables first, convert them to symbols, then embrace the results variables, like this:

```
  change_indicators <- function(data, var){
  #create new variable names first, and use the rlang::sym() function to convert from string to symbol
  var_new <- sym(var)
  cont_var <- sym(paste0("cont_chg_", var))
  cat_var <- sym(paste0("cat_chg_", var))
  bi_var <- sym(paste0("bi_chg_", var))
  
  data %>%
    
    # select only percent rent burden vars
    select(tractid, year, contains("prburden")) %>%
    
    # group by tractid and count # of tracts by group 
    group_by(tractid) %>% 
    
    # create rent burden change indicator - continuous
    mutate({{cont_var}}:= {{var_new}}[year == 2019] - {{var_new}}[year == 2000]) %>%
    
    # create rent burden change indicator - categorical
    mutate({{cat_var}} := case_when({{cont_var}} < 0 ~ "negative",
                                            {{cont_var}} == 0 ~ "zero",
                                            {{cont_var}} > 0  ~ "positive" ,
                                            TRUE ~ "NA")) %>%
    # create rent burden change indicator - binary
    mutate({{bi_var}} := case_when({{cat_var}} == "negative" ~ "loss",
                                           {{cat_var}} == "positive" ~ "gain",
                                           TRUE ~ "NA")) %>%
    
    
    
    glimpse() 
  
}
```

Here is the output when I run this on your data, after ungrouping the df first:

```
rburden_data2 <- read_rds("data/rburden_data2.rds") %>% 
  ungroup()

# use a quote here, because in previous comments you loop through a vector
test <-  change_indicators(data = rburden_data2, 
                           var = "prburden")  

Rows: 219,246
Columns: 10
Groups: tractid [73,082]
$ tractid           <chr> "01001020100", "01001020100", "01001020100", "01001020200", "…
$ year              <chr> "2000", "2013", "2019", "2000", "2013", "2019", "2000", "2013…
$ prburden_no       <dbl> 60.73620, 67.88991, 44.64286, 46.07843, 42.90429, 33.85214, 6…
$ prburden          <dbl> 14.110429, 13.761468, 35.119048, 16.666667, 3.300330, 24.1245…
$ prburden_sev      <dbl> 17.177914, 18.348624, 18.452381, 26.470588, 43.564356, 38.521…
$ prburden_not      <dbl> 7.975460, 0.000000, 1.785714, 10.784314, 10.231023, 3.501946,…
$ prburden_all      <dbl> 31.28834, 32.11009, 53.57143, 43.13725, 46.86469, 62.64591, 2…
$ cont_chg_prburden <dbl> 21.0086182, 21.0086182, 21.0086182, 7.4578470, 7.4578470, 7.4…
$ cat_chg_prburden  <chr> "positive", "positive", "positive", "positive", "positive", "…
$ bi_chg_prburden   <chr> "gain", "gain", "gain", "gain", "gain", "gain", "gain", "gain…
```

This skirts the problem of trying to convert to a symbol within other functions (like case_when), which can be a headache.

Comment: Thx, Connor. This also works. The next follow up question I have is how to get this function to run over several variables. `vars <-  c("prburden", "prburden_sev", "prburden_all") 
mytest <- map_df(vars, get_change_connor(data = rburden_data,             
                                         var = vars))` doesn't seem to work